# Record audio and video by using FFmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

I tried to record audio and video at the same time by using FFmpeg. However, several problems occurred. Here is my code:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ar 24000 -i plughw:1 -acodec aac -strict experimental -f video4linux2 -y -r 4 -i /dev/video0 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf:expansion=strftime:text='%Y-%m-%d %H\\:%M\\:%S': fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.8:x=w-text_w:y=h-line_h" -vframes 20 -vcodec mpeg4 out.mp4
```

And the result which I copied is shown below:

```
ffmpeg version N-61372-g1306359 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar 19 2014 22:59:34 with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1)
  configuration: --enable-cross-compile --cross-prefix= --arch=armel --target-os=linux --prefix=/usr --enable-gpl --enable-libfreetype --enable-nonfree --enable-libaacplus --extra-cflags=-I/usr/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/lib --extra-libs=-ldl
  libavutil      52. 66.101 / 52. 66.101
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavdevice    55. 11.100 / 55. 11.100
  libavfilter     4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, alsa, from 'plughw:1':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1395351824.134003, bitrate: 768 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 24000 Hz, stereo, s16, 768 kb/s
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x21c1840] The driver changed the time per frame from 1/4 to 1/5
Input #1, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 15130.155369, bitrate: 24576 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 24576 kb/s, 5 fps, 5 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0x21c14f0] expansion=strftime is deprecated.
libaacplus: bad aac setting: br:128000, AACch:2, AACsr:24000
[libaacplus @ 0x21c6370] libaacplus doesn't support this output format!
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 640x480, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 4 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac, 24000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo -> mpeg4)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le -> libaacplus)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

It shows that `libaacplus doesn't support this output format!`. It worked very well while I was changing the output format to mpg. However, there was no sound in the final output file. I am not sure which parts goes wrong. Could somebody help me?

Does the `libfaac` support `mp4`?

Comment: libaacplus is an AAC-HE encoder. Are you sure this is what you want? Can you show the output of: `ffmpeg -h encoder=libaacplus`?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thank you for answering. The output is `Threading capabilities:no` `Supported sample format:s16 flt` `Supported channel layouts: mono stereo` What I want is record a mp4 file with video and audio in it.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard BTW, does it mean that mp4 is not supported or the audio codec? I also tried `-acodec pcm_s16le` and got the same problem.

Comment: As far as I know PCM, or at least that variant, is not supported in MP4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option placement matters:

```
ffmpeg [global options] [input options] -i input [output options] output
```

You told `ffmpeg` to use `-acodec aac -strict experimental` as an input options for your v4l2 device, but this was ignored. Since `ffmpeg` will give other supported encoders priority over the native AAC encoder it chose libaacplus which is not compatible with the options you provided it. This is an AAC-HE encoder, but I'm assuming you want a normal AAC-LC format. See the [FFmpeg and AAC Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AACEncodingGuide) for more details.

You have to move `-acodec aac -strict experimental` to be an output option:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ar 24000 -i plughw:1 -f v4l2 -r 4 -i /dev/video0 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf:expansion=strftime:text='%Y-%m-%d %H\\:%M\\:%S': fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.8:x=w-text_w:y=h-line_h" -vframes 20 -vcodec mpeg4 -acodec aac -strict experimental out.mp4
```

Comment: Brilliant. It worked! Thank you so much. Sorry that I can't vote this answer because my low reputation.